# Figuring out RegEx search term

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm very new to this whole thing. I am using regex to extract data from an HTML which contains:

```
<p class="bold"> Last Statement:</p>
<p>Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I want to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y&rsquo;all and consider y&rsquo;all my sisters I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden. </p>
```

I am trying to extract the text using

```
word = re.findall('Last Statement:</p>.*<p>(.+)</p>', x)
```

But it's giving me an empty list. How can I debug that?

Comment: Try using a tool like https://regex101.com/ to test your regex. You might also want to use a HTML parser instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: By default, regex will only look on one line for a pattern match, but your pattern spans across multiple lines.  Pass an additional argument `re.DOTALL` to the `findall()` function to enable multiline matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were almost here. replacing .* by \s* should make it work.

```
word = re.findall('Last Statement:</p>\s*<p>(.+)</p>', x)
```

e.g.

```
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = """
<p class="bold"> Last Statement:</p>
<p>Yes sir. I  would like to thank God, my dad, my Lord Jesus savior for saving me and changing  my life. I want to apologize to my in-laws for causing all this emotional pain.  I love y&rsquo;all and consider y&rsquo;all my sisters I never had. I want to thank you for  forgiving me. Thank you warden. </p>
        """
    word = re.findall('Last Statement:</p>\s*<p>(.+)</p>', s)
    print(word)
```

since you are processing html, it might be better tough to use an xml parser + xpath to find the text you are interested in...